# I would like to fit the image in the image view with out having the blank spaces

Tags: android

I have given the image view of certain size the image which i have smaller size than the image view when i fit the image view it is looking like the picture is at the corner but i would like to get the picture in certain pattern such as after filling the smaller image in the image view on the corner the remaining space of the image view should be filled with the same smaller pic until it fits the size of the image view.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android:scaleType="fitXY" and android:adjustViewBounds="true". This will work in your case.

Comment: But i want to fill the whole image view with the several small images

Comment: If you want to add more then 1 ImageView then you have to set ImageViews with your  own, because you cant set more then one Image in one ImageView. And if you want to give background, then you need to give it to Your Parent layout which contains ImageView.

Comment: if you see the twitter background image if we upload a small picture then it will show the same picture several times i would like to get like that

Comment: For that you need to create it custom, using your logic, no pre defined things in Android that I have seen.

Comment: sure...I will if I get

Comment: this is how i would want to see the image

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add scaleType attribute in your xml file

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: But i want to fill the whole image view with the several small images

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file where the ImageView component is you can add this attribute

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: But i want to fill the whole image view with the several small images

Comment: Try this, 
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout); 
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
params.leftMargin = 50; params.topMargin = 60; 
rl.addView(iv, params);

and then add this r1 in your main view then again change margin, height and other param and add again like this you do n no of times